# how to rotate a JFreeChart in iText pdf

Tags: java, pdf, awt, itext, jfreechart

I have created a servlet to handle the save of a JFreeChart displayed in a JSP to a PDF file. 
The code I am using so far is:

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.DefaultFontMapper;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfTemplate;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class ChartPrintServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2445101551756014281L;

    protected void doPost ( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        JFreeChart jFreeChart = (JFreeChart) request.getSession().getAttribute("jFreeChart");
        String url = "";
        int height = 1024;
        int width = 1152;

        if (jFreeChart == null) 
        {
            url = "/do/error";
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {

            AbsencesGanttChartPostProcessor postProc = new AbsencesGanttChartPostProcessor();
            postProc.processChart(jFreeChart, null);
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"absences.pdf\"");
            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

            try
            {   
                Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(width, height);
                Document document = new Document(pagesize.rotate(), 30, 30, 30, 30);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
                document.open();
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
                PdfTemplate tp = cb.createTemplate(height, width);
                Graphics2D g2 = tp.createGraphics(height, width, new DefaultFontMapper());

                Rectangle2D r2D = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, height, width);
                jFreeChart.draw(g2, r2D);
                g2.dispose();
                cb.addTemplate(tp, 0, 0);
                document.close();
            }
            catch (DocumentException de) 
            {
                System.err.println(de.getMessage());
            }
            finally
            {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void doGet ( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doPost(request, response);
    }
}
```

I have swapped the height and width everywhere in order to get the PDF to look half-decent, but what I really want is to be able to create a PDF as if it were in landscape mode.

If I try

```
Graphics2D g2 = tp.createGraphics(height, width, new DefaultFontMapper());
g2.rotate(90)
```

then the PDF just prints a white, blank page.

What is the correct way with the itext / Java awt APIs to go about rotating the entire document (including the JFreeChart underneath) when creating a PDF?

Comment: Pop the image in a dialog & I think you will discover the problem has nothing to do with PDF (i.e. the code is broken before that point).  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (that uses J2SE exclusively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First this: your referring to my name in your code. I'd like you to use itextpdf instead. See http://lowagie.com/itext2

Now for your question. There's an easy way to achieve what you want, and there's a more difficult way.

You only use three parameters in this method: `cb.addTemplate(tp, 0, 0);` which means that you only want iText to do a translation (zero up, zero to the right). If you also want a rotation, you need to use the method with seven parameters, six of which define the transformation matrix. This is simple algebra; it's explained in my book "iText in Action", but most of the developers I know don't like doing math and they say this is the difficult way.

The easy way, is to wrap tp inside an Image object, and rotate the image:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(tp);
img.setRotationDegrees(90);
```

There's also a `setRotation()` method that takes radians as a parameter.

Additional notes:

1. Don't worry about the Image class rasterizing your content. A `PdfTemplate` wrapped inside an `Image` object will result in a Form XObject, it won't be changed into an Image XObject.
2. Be careful not to rotate your image 'outside your page'. You may need to take into account the pivot point.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments, however the underlying image seems to be unchanged. I have pasted the modified code above with some screenshots

Comment: The missing items were part of [edit/2](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13864220/2), since [revised](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13864220/revisions).

Comment: OK, I found them, but now the question is even less clear. The way I interpret that edit is: Bizmark creates a chart with a width or X and a height of Y. It seems that he wants the chart to be redrawn entirely when he rotates the chart. That doesn't make much sense, I'm inclined to downvote the question without further clarification.

Comment: Well, yes, I was looking for a way to redraw it, why else call rotate on the graphic? Essentially I would like the PDF to be created as if it were in landscape when the chart was originally displayed (in a browser) as portrait so the user does not have to print it in landscape or otherwise fiddle with the layout after opening the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You rotate your Graphics counterclockwise around the top left corner, and doing so moves everything out of the drawing area. This is why you just get the blank page. You need to apply translation also to shift graphics back into the painting area. Translate y downwards by the width of you image:

```
        g.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
        g.translate(0, width);
```

Also, [Graphics2D.rotate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate%28double%29) expects radians, not degrees.

After that, JFreeChart should draw the transformed chart if you pass transformed Graphics2D for it.

Comment: That's probably because you rotated the image outside the visible area of the template. I think you would see the syntax to draw the chart if you opened the PDF in a tool that allows you to see the content stream.

Comment: translate by -width worked for me. Also remember if you are writing the rotated/translated image somewhere, you will have to switch the height and width dimensions.